# PGP Encryption/Decryption in Adobe Flash

Tags: flash, encryption

Is it possible to make PGP encryption/decription in Adobe Flash Application?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah--it's totally possible. You should use a crypto library for Flash such as [as3crypto](http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/).